# Ошибка линковки библиотеки libzmq в Qt creator на Windows 10

Tags: c++, qt, qtcreator, zeromq

Я хочу использовать библиотеку libzmq/cppzmq в своем проекте в Qt Creator, но при сборке программы получаю ошибку. Перед этим я предварительно собрал libzmq через Qt (Компилятор MSVC 2019 64bit)

Ошибка сборки:

**C:\projects\zmq\test2\libzmq.dll:-1: ошибка: LNK1107: ­Ґ¤®ЇгбвЁ¬л© Ё«Ё Ї®ўаҐ¦¤Ґ­­л© д ©«: ­Ґ г¤ Ґвбп Їа®зЁв вм Ї® 0x360**

Код проекта, в котором я пытаюсь воспользоваться этой библиотекой (Компилятор MSVC 2019 64bit):

- .pro файл

```
CONFIG += console c++11
CONFIG -= app_bundle
CONFIG -= qt

# libzmq
LIBS += C:\Tedeev\projects\zmq\test2\libzmq.dll
INCLUDEPATH += C:\Tedeev\projects\zmq\test2\zmq_test2\include

# заголовочные cppzmq
INCLUDEPATH += C:\Tedeev\projects\zmq\cppzmq-master

SOURCES += \
        main.cpp
```

- main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include "zmq.hpp"

using namespace std;

int main()
{
   
    return 0;
}
```

**P.S** Я также пытался собрать проект компилятором mingw64, но в этом случае даже ошибку не выводит, программа аварийно завершается.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Судя по [этому](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/error-messages/tool-errors/linker-tools-error-lnk1107?view=vs-2019), что-то не то пытаетесь линковать - а именно .dll-файл, а не как положено, .lib...

```
LIBS += C:\Tedeev\projects\zmq\test2\libzmq.dll
```

Comment: а как же тогда пользоваться .dll файлами в Qt? Если не добавить их через LIBS, то Qt их не находит.

Comment: Пользоваться - это одно, а линковать - другое. Линковать нужно .lib-файл, который вы должны были собрать с dll вместе (ваше *я предварительно собрал libzmq*). Если нет - ну, посмотрите, например, https://qna.habr.com/q/10192 или, скажем, https://overcoder.net/q/107538/%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%81%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%84%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BB-lib-%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%84%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BB-dll-%D0%B8-%D1%84%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BB-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B0. Ошибка линковщика говорит как раз о том, что использован не тот формат...

Comment: подключил .lib и запустилось, спасибо за помощь